# Attempting to replicate already working code, but encountering an error during import

Tags: python, python-3.x

A very simple question with a lot of context behind it, so thanks in advance for your patience. In summary I am attempting to control a DAC/ADC development board by adapting already existing software written in python. However, I am encountering an error when I simply try to import some of the prerequisites.
The board I am attempting to control is the [ZCU111](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/zcu111.html). The ZCU111 has an ARM processor on board and some wonderful folks found a way to put linux on board; [Pynq](http://www.pynq.io/). The pynq software is imaged onto a SD card, and the SD card is mounted onto the ZCU111 board and the processor boots from the card. I communicate to the board through a USB serial interface and a hosted SSH server on the ZCU111.
Using pynq, some modules have been created to control automatically set the inner workings of the ZCU111 board, [ZCU111 GitHub](https://github.com/Xilinx/ZCU111-PYNQ).
Using those modules someone created some great Jupiter notebooks that help run the ZCU111 though a nice gui interface; [RFSoC_SAM](https://github.com/strath-sdr/rfsoc_sam). However, I dont want run the board through a notebook or gui, I wanted to adapt parts of the code to a much simpler .py file to be run from the terminal.
[image of filing system on SD card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFPf8.png)
To the left is an image of the filing system on the SD card. The GitHub folder contains the modules to control the inner workings, and its identical to the link above. The Jupiter notebook folder contains the notebook which I wish to emulate and works as expected. The pynq folder contains the modules for pynq itself. The Sami_py folder is where I placed my test code.
Here are where my problems and questions begin: The Notebook that works begins with 2 lines of code:

```
from rfsoc_sam.overlay import 
sam = Overlay()
```

When I scour the SD card, I can't find rfsoc_sam anywhere on the SD card. I'm confused how it works? The GitHub listed above for the RFSoC_Sam DOES have the accompanying .py files. Why do'nt those .py files appear on my SC card? Does the Jupiter notebook package all the necessary files? Regardless the first step in creating my own software is to import the same modules the Overlay from the rfsoc_sam module does. Despite it not appearing on the SD card, I can open the file from the GitHub

```
from pynq import Overlay, allocate
import xrfclk
import xrfdc
import os
from .hierarchies import *
from .quick_widgets import Image
from ipywidgets import IntProgress
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
import threading
```

That is everything that needed to be imported, however I just wanted to start with xrfclk. Since that folder and init file can be found on the SD card in the GitHub folder, the same folder from the link above, [ZCU111 GitHub](https://github.com/Xilinx/ZCU111-PYNQ).
I wrote a .py file placed in the Sami_py folder:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '//192.168.2.99/xilinx/GitHub/ZCU111-PYNQ/ZCU111/packages/xrfclk')
import xrfclk
```

The error message I receive:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sami_py/RFSoC_Trial.py", line 3, in <module>
    import xrfclk
ImportError: No module named xrfclk
```

I thought I pointed to the right directory, do i need to point to the directory that has the *init* file directly? I am not sure why i can't get the include to work, any thoughts?

Happy to provide more context. Thanks in advance for any help or advnce,
Sami

Comment: Did you try adding `//192.168.2.99/xilinx/GitHub/ZCU111-PYNQ/ZCU111/packages` to the Python path instead ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear you're having problems with RFSoC SAM. I created this project and can give you some help about RFSoC and PYNQ.

Firstly, the RFSoC SAM package is installed and maintained using pip, which is the python package manager. As PYNQ v2.6 uses Python3, we need to invoke the pip3 command to install RFSoC SAM. In the repository [readme](https://github.com/strath-sdr/rfsoc_sam), you will see that installing RFSoC SAM on the ZCU111 has a few steps. You need to connect your board to the internet for these steps to work correctly. You should also use the terminal in the Jupyter Labs environment to run the commands (this is detailed in the repository readme). The first step is a patch for the xrfdc package, and looks a bit like this:

`mkdir /home/xilinx/GitHub cd /home/xilinx/GitHub/ git clone https://github.com/dnorthcote/ZCU111-PYNQ cd /home/xilinx/GitHub/ZCU111-PYNQ cp /home/xilinx/GitHub/ZCU111-PYNQ/ZCU111/packages/xrfdc/pkg/xrfdc/__init__.py /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xrfdc/__init__.py`

The reason a patch is required is because the xrfdc package needs an update that has not yet been implemented for the ZCU111, but it has been implemented for the RFSoC2x2. I simply moved these updates over to the ZCU111, which means RFSoC SAM will function correctly. If you do not implement this patch, the notebook for RFSoC SAM will fail to load. I am not in charge of the xrfdc package, which is why the package needs to be patched (not version controlled and updated).

After implementing the xrfdc patch, you can install RFSoC SAM via pip. The command looks a bit like this:

`pip3 install git+https://github.com/strath-sdr/rfsoc_sam`

This command will install the RFSoC SAM package to the following location:

*/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rfsoc-sam*

This location is where all pip packages are stored for PYNQ v2.6. You should not attempt to directly modify packages in this location as they are all under version control. If you would like to develop and change the RFSoC SAM source code, then you need to consider a slightly different workflow.

The RFSoC SAM package does not have any developer tools. To make changes to the project, I simply Git clone the project to my Jupyter workspace in PYNQ, and then make changes to the project. When I'm ready, I can simply reinstall the package by running the following command in a Jupyter Labs terminal:

`pip3 install .`

This command will just reinstall RFSoC SAM, but using the offline changes you make instead. Using this workflow, you could easily create a fork of RFSoC SAM, make changes to the source code, commit those changes, and easily install the package on your ZCU111. This workflow is something you should consider.

You may be more interested in trying out RFSoC + PYNQ projects that are of lower complexity. For instance, you will be able to see the following projects: [RFSoC QPSK](https://github.com/strath-sdr/rfsoc_qpsk) and [RFSoC Radio](https://github.com/strath-sdr/rfsoc_radio). You may have also seen the [RFSoC Workshop](https://github.com/Xilinx/PYNQ_RFSOC_Workshop).

Going forward, I would recommend investigating the above projects, and also understanding Linux and pip a little better. A few google searches should get you on the right path here. Try to create your own pip package and a Github repository to store the package. If you can do this, you will have greatly improved your understanding of pip, and the PYNQ operating system.

Also, If you have questions in the future, you can use the [PYNQ discussion page] (https://discuss.pynq.io/). I will be able to find your questions faster here.

If you have any further issues, feel free to drop me a message. You can also use the [RFSoC SAM issues page](https://github.com/strath-sdr/rfsoc_sam/issues) in the repository, which helps me track these type of questions a little easier.

David N.